# Does entity framework 3.5 support composite keys made up from foreign keys?

Tags: entity-framework

We have a table which has a composite primary key consisting of two foreign keys. I know that this should work on EF 4.0 but we get an update exception when trying to insert the referenced entities when using EF 3.5.

I tried to look for confirmation whether or not EF 3.5 supports this but the answer seems to always be "Yes, EF 4.0 supports this".

So I'm asking here:

Does entity framework **3.5** support composite keys made up from foreign keys?

Comment: Nope, luckily I'm not working on that project anymore. :-D Seems like this would be an easy question to answer though. :-/